# Generics with any number of generic?

Tags: generics, rust

Making an ecs, I've been trying to create entities from a few components, using any number of these for user simplicity :

```rust
    pub fn create_entity_with_1<C: Component<C> + 'static>(&mut self, component: C) -> Entity {
        // C is a component
        let result: Entity = Entity {
            id: self.last_entity_id,
        };
        self.last_entity_id += 1;
        // add the component, as we just created the entity we can fast push in the packed array
        self.components.add_comp_to_last(&result, component);
        return result;
    }

    pub fn create_entity_with_2<C1: Component<C1> + 'static,
                                C2: Component<C2> + 'static>
                                (&mut self, component_1: C1,
                                            component_2: C2) -> Entity {
        // C is a component
        let result: Entity = Entity {
            id: self.last_entity_id,
        };
        self.last_entity_id += 1;
        // add the component, as we just created the entity we can fast push in the packed array
        self.components.add_comp_to_last(&result, component_1);
        self.components.add_comp_to_last(&result, component_2);

        return result;
    }
```

Clearly, if I extend this to more components, the pattern of this function will always be the same, and I don't want to have 15 of these.

Is there a way to write a generic taking arbitrary number of generic components ?

Alternatively, I've seen [The legion ecs](https://github.com/amethyst/legion) does this taking a tuple of components, but I can't figure out how to unpack tuples of any sizes.

Comment: How does `add_comp_to_last` handle this? Does it box the components into trait objects?

Comment: @isaactfa it moves the component in a vec, in some kind of component table. But no, components are stored as structs, not as trait objects

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? If your function takes a `C1: Component` and a `C2: Component` you can't ordinarily store them in the same `Vec`.

Comment: @isaactfa my component table is an anymap (map of any, with typeid as key, it's an existing crate) of vec of components. So they are not in the same vec, and when I add components to the table they are stored in their corresponding vecs. With two different components, they will be in two different vecs.

Comment: Then I'm afraid the short answer is no, this isn't possible. The slightly longer answer is that it _might_ be possible with declarative macros (although I can't think of an elegant way off the top of my head); and the long answer is that it's possible with [proc macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) though they can get pretty annoying to implement.

Comment: The right approach is probably to have a single function that takes a single argument implementing trait `IntoComponents`, implement `IntoComponents` for `(C1, C2, C3, ...) where C1: Component<C1>, C2: Component<C2>, ...`then use a macro to generate the implementations of that trait for the tuples up to some relatively high arity, where the implementations call `self.components.add_comp_to_last` for each of the tuple's elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! create_entity_fns {
    (
        $first_fn_name:ident $first_generic:ident
        $( $fn_name:ident $generic:ident )*
    ) => {
        #[allow(non_snake_case)]
        pub fn $first_fn_name<
            $first_generic: Component<$first_generic> + 'static,
            $( $generic: Component<$generic> + 'static, )*
        >(
            &mut self,
            $first_generic: $first_generic,
            $( $generic: $generic, )*
        ) -> Entity {
            let result = Entity { id: self.last_entity_id };
            self.last_entity_id += 1;

            self.components.add_to_last(&result, $first_generic);
            $( self.components.add_to_last(&result, $generic); )*

            result
        }
        
        create_entity_fns!( $( $fn_name $generic )* );
    };

    () => {};
}

impl Foo {
    create_entity_fns!(
        // Notice the swapped order!
        // ...
        create_entity_with_4 C4
        create_entity_with_3 C3
        create_entity_with_2 C2
        create_entity_with_1 C1
    );
}
```

For each invocation we create a function and recurse to the next invocation with one less parameters.